# Sveltekit + prisma db + multiple databases

Tags: svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I write a Web App which of course uses its own DB, for simplicity I choose prisma db for the DB stuff. However, everything works fine until I reached the point, where I need to connect to a **second** database with **existing** tables. With some search I found this [posting](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118) and it make sense, so I changed my Code like:

prisma/schema.prisma > prisma/schema1.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/client1"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

and added prisma/schema2.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./generated/client2"
}

datasource db2 {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_PYTHON_URL")
}
```

The pull command creates the schema2.prisma Models successfully, and the generate command generates the prisma/generated/client1 and client2 folders.

My db.js:

```
// import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { PrismaClient1 } from './prisma/generated/client1'
import { PrismaClient2 } from './prisma/generated/client2'

// export const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const client1 = new PrismaClient1();
export const client2 = new PrismaClient2();
```

After starting the dev Server again, I faced this error:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at ./prisma/generated/client1:2:23
> at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Svelte/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:52420:15

I tried to delete the node_modules and reinstall everything but facing still the same error.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Before all other references to JavaScript add the

```
<script>var exports = {};</script>
```

If this wouldn't help in your particular case, try all other tips and tricks from the [ReferenceError: exports is not defined in TypeScript](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: Hi Damir, thanks for sharing. Sadly it does not work or better I am not able to make it work. I added the script into the app.html of Sveltekit and got no effect. Changing the tsconfig.json does not help as well. If I delete the type: module in the package.json I get an error: "X [ERROR] No known conditions for "./vite" specifier in "@sveltejs/kit" package [plugin externalize-deps]" Any other suggestions?

Comment: The only advice at the moment is to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it. This is win-win, making it you could find the solution on the clean or and you will provide sandbox for others to help you.